# Content resolver turns red inside fragment from a public void onActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to access the image gallery and I have these code. Content Resolver turned red in the fragment. I've been trying tweaks, but still it isn't solved.

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null && data.getData() != null){
        Uri filepath = data.getData();
        bitmap = (Bitmap) MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver, filepath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these variations:

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
```

or simply

```
getActivity().getContentResolver()
```

Comment: public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null && data.getData() != null){
            Uri filepath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = (Bitmap) MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filepath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }


Does this work out sir?

Comment: no mroe errors but im still doubting, i still didnt run my app though sir.

Comment: @shielamekelele is your app crashing? what's the stacktrace?

Comment: It didnt crash sir. I was not finished yet with the gallery selection. I will keep posted sir hope you are with me

Comment: @shielamekelele I'll be glad to help if I can!

Comment: I am currently encoding for my gallery selection sir! I hope you are there for me when I need help. Im so glad to have someone like you!

Comment: If you require coding help, you're in the right place! ;)

Comment: soo much love energy! all hail professional coders! thanks so much!

Comment: Sir are you there? I need help now. everything is fine until i selected an image, it says it returned a null ID sir. can we talk?

Comment: @shielamekelele can you please create a separate question with all the relevant info and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: gonna do sir! hope you tune in

Comment: Sir, I can't post for now because this post didnt last for 90mins. I guess I'm gonna wait for awhile :( wish I could get this done as soon as possible sir :( I got no sleep for now.